# bxSlider destroy and initialise based on viewport resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, each, bxslider

I'm using the script bellow on a page that contains multiple sliders build with [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/options). I need the sliders elements to be stacked on small screens (which is the initial state) and become part of a slider on large screens.

```
function accordionSliderToggle() {
  // get slider containers
  var sliders = $('.js-desktop-slider-holder');
  // check viewport size
  var desktop = checkWindowWidth();
  var initSliders, destroySliders, totalSliders = [];

  initSliders = function() {
    $(sliders).each(function(i) {
      // Slider target elements
      var targetSlider = $(this).find('.js-accordion-slider');
      var targetPager = $(this).find('.js-accordion-slider-nav');
      var targetSlideTitle = $(this).find('.slide-title');

      // Initialize slider
      var sliderObj = $(targetSlider).bxSlider({
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        infiniteLoop: false,
      });
      // push sliders to array
      totalSliders.push(sliderObj);
    });
  };

  destroySliders = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < totalSliders.length; i++) {
      totalSliders[i].destroySliders();
    }
  };

  if (desktop) {

    initSliders();

  } else {

    destroySliders();

  }
}

accordionSliderToggle();

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
    setTimeout(accordionSliderToggle, 300);
  } else {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(accordionSliderToggle);
  }
});
```

[bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/options) has method `destroySlider()` however when I resize the window from small to large, the sliders get initialised, but if I resize from large to small, they don't get destroyed.

Comment: Isn't the `targetSlider` already a jQuery collection ? Not sure, but can you try to initialize them like so `var sliderObj = targetSlider.bxSlider({...` ?

Comment: @DavidDomain I tried as you suggested but the sliders still remain initialised when going back to small viewport.